# Flight paths linking placemarks using Java Api For Kml(JAK)

Tags: kml, google-earth, jak

Currently i'm having a project which requires to set placemarks and link them with polylines (i suppose), lines which have an arc to it, with properly segmented portions to the arc. I've been able to generate kml file with jak library. But i can't produce more den 1 placemark in the kml file. And i'm quite stuck at the link of paths.

http://www.barnabu.co.uk/google-earth-complete-us-air-routes/

This website is something that is close to what i'm required to do. I'm very new towards kml and java so please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know where in the development process you are stuck, I may give only a generic advise at this stage:

It helped me a lot to create a sample KML file by hand and determine the structures I needed for my GE/API project. I then was able to select the correct functions to add elements to the KML tree dynamically. Check the code used by [this](http://dauda.at/locator/) page - maybe you can get some inspirations

Hope that helps

Comment: just saw your other question on marshaling and the hints about KML files being text files. Note: function PaintSubField(Coord) in js file found in above page link does exactly that ... peek in

Comment: Thanks Mike, i will check on the website soon. Any more help from anyone would be appreciated as well. Thanks